# Convergence of the series for $a \in \mathbb R$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{n^2+a^2} \right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Convergence of the series for $a \in \mathbb R$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{n^2+a^2} \right)$$

I saw this problem in a calculus book and it gave a hint that says

**HINT** First show that $$\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{n^2+a^2} \right)=(-1)^n\sin\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n}\sim(-1)^n\frac{\pi a^2}{2n}\qquad  (n \to\infty)$$

I was able to show that $$\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{n^2+a^2} \right)=\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{n^2+a^2} -\pi n+\pi n\right)=\sin\left(\pi (\sqrt{n^2+a^2}-n)+\pi n \right)=(-1)^n\sin\left(\pi (\sqrt{n^2+a^2}-n) \right)=(-1)^n\sin\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n}$$

But what I don't understand is how did they come up with that equivalence? First I thought that they used the limit comparison test but now I can see that you can't use that test because we're dealing with alternating series. Did they do a mistake or something?

Can somebody help me understand this hint and how to solve this problem?

Comment: To obtain that asymptotic expression, use the fact that $\sin(1/n)\sim 1/n$ as $n\to \infty$ (to see why this is true, recall the standard limit $\lim\limits_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin \theta }{\theta} =1$).

Comment: Make sure to not use the fact that they are equivalent asymptotically too directly.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Isn't that a limit that you're using? I'm sorry but we haven't really use the asymptotic expressions. I was confused because I know that you can't use a limit for alternating series. What is the difference here?

Comment: A word of caution: We cannot use the asymptotic relation directly to apply alternating series test. It shows that the magnitude converges to zero as $n\to\infty$, but it does not conclusively answer whether the magnitude decreases montonically, which is also a requirement for the alternating series test. To this end, just argue directly that $\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n}$ decreases in $n$, and so, $\sin\left(\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n}\right)$ decreases for large $n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Okay thank you very much I understand now. So this hint was just to show that $\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{n^2+a^2} \right)$ converges to zero as $n \to \infty $. If I could select my answer to a comment I would select yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first half of the hint is enough to conclude the convergence of the series.

Indeed, notice that $a_n := \pi a^2/(\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n)$ decreases monotonically to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, and so, $\sin(a_n)$ decreases monotonically to $0$ for large $n$. (For an explicit range of $n$ for which this claim is valid, just pick any $N$ such that $a_N \in [0, \pi/2]$. Then this claim is true for the range $n \geq N$, thanks to the monotonicity of $\sin x$ over $[0, \pi/2]$.)

Then what is the use of the asymptotic formula for $\sin(a_n)$? The advantage is that we can predict the behavior of the series. Indeed, from $\sin(a_n) \sim (-1)^n \pi a^2/ 2n$ we can read out that

1. $\sum \sin(a_n)$ does not converge absolutely, but
2. somehow alternating series test may be applicable.

So, although the relation cannot be utilized directly, we can set up the direction of our proof.

Answer (score 0):

For small $x$ we have that $\sin{(x)} \approx x$. One can prove this from the Taylor series expansion of $\sin{(x)}$. As 
$$\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n} \approx \frac{\pi a^2}{2n}$$ for large $n$ and $1/n$ is very small for large $n$ we then have
$$(-1)^n\sin\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n} \approx (-1)^n\frac{\pi a^2}{2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sin\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+a^2}-\pi n\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n}\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $\sin\left(\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n}\right)$ decreases monotonically to $0$ for $n\ge a^2$. That is, for $n\ge a^2$, $\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n}\le\frac{\pi a^2}{2n}\le\frac\pi2$ and $\sin(x)$ maps $[0,\pi/2]$ monotonically onto $[0,1]$.